# WCF web service config ReceiveTimeout

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

the Binding > ReceiveTimeout is not set in my config, and the application crashes I guess after the default value.

How can I set it to no limit? and why do I need timeouts on the first place. I want my application to run forever without crashing because of timeouts.

And pointers to learn all about web service configurations, I find them confusing and have no grasp over it. I always google and then there's hit and trial. Any books, articles, tutorials?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default timeout for a client is 60 seconds, at which time it will throw an exception.  Really, you should try/catch the exception and do something to handle a timeout, not wait forever. You can increase the timeout in your binding configuration. See here:

[Increasing the timeout value in a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424358/increasing-the-timeout-value-in-a-wcf-service)

Also here, scroll down to the "sendTimeout" element:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, look at using asynchronous operations if you have a long-running call, as you don't want the call to block while it waits for a response from the server.