# Increase time allowed for service to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a service that I am using that is just too slow, when I write a console app for it it takes like 5 minutes to load.

I am using it as part of my service, so when client calls it, my service times out before it finishes consuming the other service.

Is there anything I can do client/server that will allow it to finish?

Comment: Sure. profile your code to find the bottlenecks and then fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF has timeout configuration options. If possible figure out why the other service is taking so long.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/424386/1967405