# The operation has timed out in WCF REST Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, rest, wcf-rest

I have created a web service using WCF [REST Service Template 40(CS)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd). When I try to consume it using

```
  var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Concat(serviceUrl, resourceUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
   if (method == "POST" && requestBody != null)
            {
                byte[] requestBodyBytes = ToByteArrayUsingJsonContractSer(requestBody);
                request.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    postStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);

            }

var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I keep getting:

**The operation has timed out**

How to increase time out ? Do I need to increase it in service or the client which is using this service with url:

http://myservice.com/RecordingCompleted/

Please suggest

Comment: Try setting SEND TIMEOUT and RECIEVE TIMEOUT in Client Config to a Higher Value

Comment: I have web.config in my service but it where these two attributes will be specified ?

Comment: I am talking about CLIENT configuration , not WCF Configuration,

Comment: do i need to add it with request ?

Comment: try modifying web.config of wcf project. More info, please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424358/increasing-the-timeout-value-in-a-wcf-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code before Call the WEb Service.

```
request.Timeout = 5000;
```

Comment: I am using  request.Timeout = 50000;      but still same error

Comment: Waht is the output of WCF method,

Comment: Thats fine, Plese check the Reason why its taking too much time, I don't advice you to put such long TimeOut, to return a String Response, this is too large